# How I change the origin of the x axis in ggplot to go from 'August to March' instead of 'Jan to March, August to December'?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot temperature data over time, with the x axis: "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01", "01-01", "02-01", "03-01"
Rather then: "01-01", "02-01", "03-01", "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01", which R is doing.

My data looks like the following- my x axis uses the Month_day column. Unique values in this column are: "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01", "01-01", "02-01", "03-01".

```
> head(upstream)
        Date daily_aveTempC Moving_Average_7day Year Month Day Month_day monthAbb Migration EmbryoDev
1 2007-08-01       13.49556            13.94947 2007    08  01     08-01      Aug  Upstream          
2 2007-08-02       13.44325            13.74864 2007    08  02     08-02      Aug  Upstream          
3 2007-08-03       12.93881            13.56086 2007    08  03     08-03      Aug  Upstream          
4 2007-08-04       12.78937            13.41106 2007    08  04     08-04      Aug  Upstream          
5 2007-08-05       13.13963            13.29029 2007    08  05     08-05      Aug  Upstream          
6 2007-08-06       13.11844            13.19651 2007    08  06     08-06      Aug  Upstream
```

I have the following code that plots Month_day (x axis) vs Moving Average 7day (y axis).

```
png(paste0(read_out_final, "Migration_Upstream_7day_MovingAve_Sal_4.png"), res=300, width = 15, height = 8, units = "in")

ggplot(data=upstream, aes(x=as.factor(Month_day), y=factor(Moving_Average_7day, levels=upstream$Month_day), color=Year, group=Year)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  theme_bw() +
  

  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 20,
                     limits=c(1,20)) +
  
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = upstream$Month_day[grep("0*-01", upstream$Month_day)]) +
  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  
  labs(title="Salmon Creek 4: Upstream Migration from August to March",
       x="Date",
       y="Temperature (7-Day Rolling Average degrees C)")

dev.off()
```

This plots the data: "01-01", "02-01", "03-01", "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01".
But I want the data plotted: "08-01", "09-01", "10-01", "11-01", "12-01", "01-01", "02-01", "03-01"

[image: image of plot from Jan to Mar, Aug to Dec]

I've seen solutions to this issue using the plot() function, but not for ggplot.

Comment: `Month_day` just needs the proper levels, `factor(Month_day, c('08-01', '09-01', ...))` but i dont understand what this is doing `y=factor(Moving_Average_7day, levels=upstream$Month_day)`, in your example `Moving_Average_7day` is continuous and `Month_day` is a character

Comment: This is month-day data and you want the data to be presented not in proper time order, is that right?  Because you want Jan 1 to come after Dec 1.  You need to use the year.  You don't have to display the year but you must use it to get the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every question on `ggplot2` that includes *"order of ... axis"* can be resolved by using `factor(., levels=)`, and explicitly controlling the order of the levels.

```r
dat <- data.frame(dt = seq(as.Date("2020-08-01"), as.Date("2021-04-01"), by="month"), y = 1:9)
dat$MonDay <- format(dat$dt, format = "%m-%d")
dat
#           dt y MonDay
# 1 2020-08-01 1  08-01
# 2 2020-09-01 2  09-01
# 3 2020-10-01 3  10-01
# 4 2020-11-01 4  11-01
# 5 2020-12-01 5  12-01
# 6 2021-01-01 6  01-01
# 7 2021-02-01 7  02-01
# 8 2021-03-01 8  03-01
# 9 2021-04-01 9  04-01

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(MonDay, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2, incorrect ordering of x-axis]

This is because `ggplot2` looks to order its variables; if numeric or integer, it's easy; if character, then it sorts it lexicographically, and it seems clear that `"08-01"` comes *after* `"04-01"` (despite the fact that the strings were formed from an object that had the opposite ordering).

```r
dat$MonDay <- factor(dat$MonDay, levels = unique(dat$MonDay[order(dat$dt)]))
ggplot(dat, aes(MonDay, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2, correct ordering of x-axis]